# compare old location with new location in iOS6 delegate

Tags: ios6, cllocationmanager

In ios6, the CLLocationManager delegate method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Is deprecated, now it's replaced by:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

To get the last location (the newest one), we get the last object on the array:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

   //[locations lastObject]
}
```

I use that method to monitor significant change in location:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]) {

        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }
}

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
         didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{

       //[locations lastObject]
    }
```

So when the application goes in the background, i start looking for significant changes in the device location, but this normally takes sometime to detect if a location change has been detected, right? What if the application goes in the background and no location change is detected, how will `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` delegate method will behave?

Answer (score 0):

This delegate method gets only called whenever there is a change in a location otherwise it never gets called.